# Proof Verification : Ex 9, Section 3.1 - Sequences, Elements of Real Analysis, Bartle

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to know, if my proof to the below problem is correct.

> Show that if $x_{n}\ge0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\lim{(x_{n})}=0$, then $\lim({\sqrt{x_{n}}})=0$.

**Proof.**

It is given that $\lim({x_n})=0$. This means that,

$(\forall\space{\epsilon>0})(\exists{K\in\mathbb{N}})$ s.t. $(n\ge{K})\implies|x_{n}-0|=x_{n}<\epsilon^2$

$\therefore{x_{n}}<\epsilon^2\implies{\sqrt{x_{n}}<\epsilon}$ for all $n\ge{K}$.

Thus, $|\sqrt{x_{n}}|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge{K}$.

Hence, $\lim(\sqrt{x_{n}})=0$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Is good. Model proof.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. From Solution Manual, p 18.

> 9. $0< \sqrt{x_n} <ε \iff 0<x_n <ε^2$.